# How to finding and replace value in a python list with new edited value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, str-replace

I am trying to write python code to find and replace value in a list.

Steps:

1. I have one element in a list `[8]`
2. I need to find the current element (8 in our case) reduce with value of 2, then add (Prefix and Suffix) as separate element in the same list `['6','8','6']`
3. Taking the first element from the latest list (`'6'`), repeat Step 1 and Step 2 (`'4','6','4'`), and replace with all the repeating/duplicate/reoccurring first element(`'6'`) of the list.`['4','6','4','8','4','6','4']`
4. Repeat the steps above until and unless we have number>0 as first element.`['2','4','2','6','2','4','2','8','2','4','2','6','2','4','2']`

another example:

```
[10]

[8,10,8]

[6,8,6,10,6,8,6]

[4,6,4,8,4,6,4,10,4,6,4,8,4,6,4]

[2,4,2,6,2,4,2,8,2,4,2,6,2,4,2,10,2,4,2,6,2,4,2,8,2,4,2,6,2,4,2]
```

I was able to do for string_length<10

```
string = '8'
i = int(string)

while i>2:
    print(string)
    temp = str(int(string[0])-2) + string[0] + str(int(string[0])-2)

    string = string.replace(string[0],temp)
    i -= 2

print(string)
```

## output:

```
8
686
4648464
242624282426242
```

for single, digit I can do it but I am facing problem for values more than 9.

can some one help me in programming this?

Is there any other way to do the same with out list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your examples are inconsistent between strings, lists of strings, and lists of ints, but the simplest option here is a list of ints, so that's what I'll use. You can always convert later if needed.

This is a great situation for recursion. You don't get the intermediate results like in the question, but the process is much more streamlined.

```
def expand(number, k=2):
    if number == k:
        return [number]
    expansion = expand(number-k, k)
    return expansion + [number] + expansion

print(expand(8))  # -> [2, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 2, 8, 2, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 2]
```

This code should be self-documenting, but let me know if anything's unclear.